# Range temp rises higher than set temperature with no error code

Tags: range, temperature

I have a 5 yr old Whirlpool range WFE745H0FS0. The temp keeps going up past the set temp by a lot with no error code given. Set to 350 goes to 500...more than a calibration fix...Control Board?

Comment: Does the oven have a digital readout that's showing you the 500° temp, or is that from a separate oven thermometer?

Comment: It could be the control board, it could be a temperature sensor. Have you checked to see if the temp sensor is reading valid values?